# First country to file patent EP2376067

Tags: filing, ep2376067

Which is the first country to file patent on DIRECTLY COMPRESSIBLE GRANULAR MICROCRYSTALLINE CELLULOSE BASED EXCIPIENT, MANUFACTURING PROCESS AND USE THEREOF 
ie. patent no. EP2376067 and whether the patent is granted or not..??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first filing was a US provisional application 61/116,025  filed 19.11.2008. That was followed by a PCT application with Filing Date:  16.11.2009 published as WO/2010/059534 on   27.05.2010. On the same day, Nov 16, 2009, a US application published as US20110288146 was filed. Later, the national stage  in several countries was entered.  I do not see that any have issued as patents.

[image]